# ActiveAdmin building parent objects in child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin

I'd like to be able to assign an industry_id to a new Business model when I create it..OR..create a new Industry instance that will be added to a new Business model when creating a new business

Here are my models

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :industry, :owner
  belongs_to :industry
end

class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many businesses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses
end
```

I have tried every way possible to create a form that will allow this but I've had no luck at all.

The Formtastic documentation doesn't appear to have any examples of this and neither does ActiveAdmin's.

Comment: This question is old but I am currently having the same issue and have been searching for a while and haven't found anything yet. Please tell me if you finally solved this somehow.